# slf4j version mismatch when using grails 1.3.7 with quartz scheduler 1.0-RC1

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, slf4j, grails-plugin

My application uses grails 1.3.7 with quartz scheduler 1.0-RC1 plugin.  It runs fine locally on tomcat when I run it using `grails run-app`.  However, when I create a war file using `grails prod war` and deploy it in WebLogic, I'm getting the below error:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
log4j:ERROR Error initializing log4j: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.trace(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:107)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.convert(BeanUtilsBean.java:1073)
```

I figured this is because grails 1.3.7 uses slf4j 1.5.8, but the quartz plugin uses 1.6.0 and hence there's a conflict.  I tried to address it by excluding the `slf4j-api` jar in `BuildConfig.groovy` like:

```
plugins {
    compile(":quartz:1.0-RC1") { excludes "slf4j-api" }
}
```

I was hoping the above config entry would prevent slf4j 1.6.0 from being downloaded and resolve the conflict.  But it isn't.  When I run `grails dependency-report`, I still see the conflict and I'm unable to deploy the application in WebLogic.

**EDIT:** Screenshot of the conflict from `grails dependency-report`:
[image]

Any pointers to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using the code below in `BuildConfig.groovy` to exclude `slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar` from the packaged war.  The suggestion was posted [here](http://tkills.blogspot.com/2011/03/grails-excluding-plugin-dependencies.html)

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar")
}
```

I also had to add `slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar` to the project's lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have conflict of jar file. Weblogic comes with sl4j by default and your war file should also contain sl4j jar file inside WEB-INF\lib folder. You can try changing class loading to parent last from admin console.

Comment: Even before deploying in WebLogic, I see that 1.6.0 is downloaded.  I have updated my post with a screenshot.  Adding the jar files in the lib folder didn't help.

Comment: Can you not remove the conflicting jar and package war again?

Comment: I tried.  But grails downloads dependencies automatically when I package the war.  I was trying to avoid this by excluding the jar dependency in BuildConfig.groovy.

Comment: When i say package war then i mean not building the project, its merely creating war file by using jar command.(similar to creating zip file)  See the link below for further information. http://www.mkyong.com/java/the-java-archive-tool-jar-examples/

Comment: Thank you for your response.  But I did not want to download all the dependencies (there are more than 20) manually and package the war and I wanted to leverage grails to do that.  I came up with an approach which worked for me. I have posted it as an answer.